# MVC2 with Ninject.Web.Mvc 2.2 and Ninject 2.2 runtime version 4.0 always asks for parameterless constructor for controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, ninject

I have a previous project running Ninject 2.0 runtime version 2.0 and now I am using Ninject in a new project and using the new Ninject, ninject web.mvc version 2.2 for runtime version 4.0.

Every single time I get the error no parameterless constructor

Invalid Operation exception

An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

What am I missing. All the bindings are registered.

Do I need to now define interfaces for Controllers as well such as  HomeController as IHomeController as I have seen in some examples, Or do I get back to using the older version

Comment: I have just switched to older version and the things work absolutely fine, so whats up with new versions anyone please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue mentioned couple of times on forums where there is no direct answer, here is the solution to the above problem, i.e., working with latest ninject

1. Download the latest Ninject from github.
2. The ninject I got for MVC2 is named as Ninject.Web.Mvc2-2.2.0.0-release-net-4.0 (runtime version 4)
3. Now during adding reference add Ninject.Web.Mvc.dll(check the version is same as above by right click properties in VS)
4. Now Add Ninject.dll from the lib folder in same parent folder (check the version as above)
5. Now Add CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter.dll from the extensions folder in lib parent folder (check the version as above.)

The missing link in all these have been the commonserviceLocator.dll and the correct version should match. This should be tried if you are sure your bindings are correct as mine were and check to see if your project work with older version.

Thanks to everyone, and good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one version that does not show activation exceptions properly but show this exception instead. Most likely the problem is a duplicated binding.

Comment: I havent done any bindings for controllers, I was assuming it will be as the last release of ninject. As soon as I switch to older version things work fine without any change

Comment: I do not mean controller bindings but any binding required as direct or indirect dependency of your controller. Either there is a missing one or one that is defined more than once.

Comment: I get this exception InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.] Why it works with older version than without any changes?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Remo Gloor said, you might want to check that MVC is set up to use Ninject correctly. I was doing some things manually on an older version of the MVC plugin and ended up needing to just bite the bullet and make Global extend the `NinjectHttpApplication` class, which I had previously been avoiding.

The error you're getting is the error you would get if MVC tries using its built-in controller factory to produce controllers. So you may want to create a custom method binding on your controller class and put a breakpoint inside to make sure it's even being invoked.

You may also want to switch to version 2.3. You can pick up the latest builds of Ninject and all its extensions [here](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project3&tab=projectOverview).

Comment: I have extended by globals with NinjectHttpApplication and as I said things work fine as soon as I switch to older version

Comment: I cant log in to the team city to get newer 2.3 version any ideas ?

Comment: @user182630 Click the "Login as a Guest" button, find the Ninject project, find the specific packages you're interested and use the "Artifacts" dropdown to grab the latest release builds.